# I am in public library, can't login, because someone else's account looks always logged in

Tags: discussion, support

I'm right now on one my university's public library computers, I press logout and log into my account. But am still another account appears.

When I click logout, Stack Overflow says "now this will clear all cookies." I click OK. On chrome settings, cleared cache, cleared again. restarted computer, still get the same someone else's account appears.

Why is that? Does it mean if I click logout, someone else can use my account afterwards?

Note: this account I asked the question is not mine either, maybe Stack Overflow should give a warning not to use the site on public computers.

Comment: Are they still logged in on another site like GMail or such?

Comment: It *might* be that the library uses a proxy that's just a tad *too* aggressive with caching.

Comment: @Bart nope.... I checked all gmail yahoo etc... actually I have cleared FULL Chrome cache. and restarted the computer.

Comment: @JoachimSauer hah, no. I Asked the IT guy, he said they have nothing special about this.

Comment: @JoachimSauer my gmail logs out normally. I didn't have this problem with other sites either. Just stackoverflow has this.

Comment: By the way, **what *is* your account** then?

Comment: -tamerkaradagli-

Comment: Have you already tried a completely new profile? `path/to/chrome.exe --user-data-dir=%TMP%\whatever` (Windows) or `chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever` (Linux, if you've installed Chrome, replace `chromium` with `google-chrome`).

Comment: @RobW problem is other people will be able to login with my account even when I click Logout.

Comment: @codingfreak I understand your problem. I asked to check with a completely new Chrome profile in order to find out whether the problem is specific to your browser's configuration, or something else.

Comment: So, I have a very pertinent question: Are you saying that *the account you are now logged into is not yours*? If what you say is happening, that's not your fault and does not necessarily mean you are in any trouble at all. Just wanting to get that for the record... I see some stuff related to account(s) that match info you've posted here, but that would be more to get handled privately, I think, and is why I asked this question despite what you said above. Also, have you possibly been using any proxies lately to try to get around this problem?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, those login credentials are stored in local storage so clearing cookies or even the whole cache won't have any effect.

You have two options:

1. Run Chrome in Incognito Mode every time.
2. Follow the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/q/519628) to clear the local storage.

(And if you don't want *your* account to be shared, use just Incognito Mode)

Comment: 1. Did that. 2. Did that too. Still see someone else's account.

Comment: @codingfreak this is weird then. Will have to wait for a dev to know what's going on.